# How to connect to a Postgres server in a Docker (1.12.0) container on a Mac?

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

The latest release of Docker doesn't use a virtual machine anymore, instead using a hypervisor to connect to the containers. This means I can no longer login to postgres with `psql`:

```
➜  postgres git:(master) ✗ docker run -d -p 5433:5432 db postgres
<sha>
➜  postgres git:(master) ✗ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
111f3bed4c52        db                  "/docker-entrypoint.s"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp   zen_hugle
➜  postgres git:(master) ✗ psql -p 5433 -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433"?
```

I have also tried specifying localhost as the host, but that results in a strange output:

```
➜  postgres git:(master) ✗ psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres
psql: %
```

Does anyone know what to do in this case? Thank you.

Comment: That second case looks like you are connected. Is something not working with that?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the problem of Docker.  Can you connect if you add `-h localhost` to the `psql` command?

Comment: Sorry about the delay in responding. Yes, I can connect to the local postgres database at the port 5432. But I cannot connect to the one at 5433, which is in the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. I discovered that you do have to specify the `-h` flag for it to work:

`psql -U postgres -p 5433 -h localhost`

You can also use the URI style connection string:

`psql postgresql://postgres:<your_password>@localhost:5433`

The default is "local socket" which does not work in the case of docker.